# Publishing on Facebook user's wall

Tags: facebook, blackberry, facebook-wall

i am developing an appon blackberry platform in which i hve to publish a message on users wall...i am able to get session id...but dont know how to proceed further...

i am doing something like this...

```
enter code here
URLEncodedPostData post = new URLEncodedPostData(URLEncodedPostData.DEFAULT_CHARSET, false);
        post.append("method", "stream.publish");
        post.append("message", "published through the Facebook API");
        post.append("session_key", sessionKey);
        post.append("attachment", null);
        post.append("action_links", null);
        post.append("target_id ", null);
        post.append("uid ", null);
```

i am sending this as post data to following url :

```
        http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?
```

and the response i am getting contains :
    101
  Invalid API key

Answer (score 2):

You should try to register your application, get API key and use in  in requests.
Register and go [www.facebook.com/developers/createapp.php](http://www.facebook.com/developers/createapp.php)